# Контролировать переходы на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как контролировать действие ,что пользыватель прошёл авторизацию?
Например пользыватель прошёл,вкладку войти и вошёл на сайт.Теперь когда он будет переключатся на другие страницы как контролировать ,что он вошёл?

```
<a href="q.html">Авторизация</a>
<a href="q2.html">Войти</a>
```

Comment: используйте бекенд, если нету токена авторизации не пропускайте на страницу!

Answer (score 0):

Кинь клиенту cookie или открой session на сервере